# Managing 'window' object in Isomorphic App with ReactJS and Flask Python

Tags: flask, reactjs, webpack, serverside-javascript, isomorphic-javascript

I am developing an application with Flask Backend with ReactJS front.
ReactJS app has been developed and bundled with webpack.

Everything works fine with client side rendering which is bundled with `webpack`.

I am now trying to add server side rendering with [python-react](https://github.com/markfinger/python-react) .

But problem is, I have to share some variables to my ReactJS app via `Jinja2 template` in base template `index.html` which has the `reactjs` root component node `<div id='react-node'></div>`.

I had to send my `routes` and `config` to my application via `jinja2` template like below ,

```
//index.html

<!doctype html>
<html>
...
...

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var STATIC_IMAGE_ROOT = "{{ url_for('static', filename='img/') }}";
  var ROUTES = { ... };
...
</script>

</html>
```

All the above js variables are being set to global `window` object .

But when I am trying to render the component in python, it throws exception for `window` object `ReactRenderingError: react: ReferenceError: window is not defined` .

What is the best way to solve this issue ?

Comment: Hi ! You use `React.renderToString` ( or `React.renderToStaticMarkup`) server side ?

Answer (score 5):

There is no window global when rendering on the server.  You can create a fake window, first checking if the window exists:

```
if (typeof(window) == 'undefined'){
    global.window = new Object();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), or a similar library to create a fake DOM.

Comment: The closer to the initialization of the app the better, in node when you define something on the global it's available to all files.  If your `npm start` is running a script called index.js, then try to define it in index.js or one of the files that index.js requires.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following to webpack config:

```
  // By default, Webpack is set up to target the browser,
  // not a Node environment. Try setting target in your config:
  target: 'node',
```